# Xcode 7 no simulator and storyboard files not opening

Tags: xcode7

I had Xcode 6.3, I upgraded to xCode 7 from mac appstore. After the update I don't see any simulators available and my storyboard files are not opening (even created new single view application).

I then even deleted the xcode and did a fresh installation, but still the same problem.

I have been looking around for the solutions and some people suggested to clear the contents of this folder /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/ but I don't have any such path available (unhide the files as well).

Please suggest if someone had faced same problem and got a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found that Websense was causing the problem. I confirmed it by restarting in safe mode and then uninstallation of Websense.

This thread helped me,

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7862